# How to write indexes in MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

How do I write indexes in MathJax? I haven't been able to find any documentation on the topic.
[image: pic]

Comment: `$a_{i}$` produces $a_{i}$. For atoms like a single letter or digit, the curly braces aren't strictly necessary, but if you want e.g. $a_{ijk}$ you need them.

Comment: This and much more you can find [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).